# How to load a list in a resolver while navigating and loading the first element in the ngrx store

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have adopted ngrx in my application with a central store to hold the data.
I am struggling to do the first loading of the data and then navigate to a default value. This has opened all kinds of questions on how should I use ngrx while reflecting the state in the URL.

Lets take two urls that the user may be able to type:

URL: /accounts/:accountNumber

- All accounts for the user should be fetched from the backend and loaded to the store.
- Details of account :accountNumber should be fetched from backend and loaded in the store.

How do I accomplish that:

- From the accounts resolver I call store.dispatch action to request enrolled accounts
- From the :accountNumber resolver I call.dispatch action to request details of the value in :accountNumber

That seems to work pretty well. and as I navigate from within the application or the user enter the URL and loads the application, the Store and the are in sync. (See the resolvers below)

URL: /accounts

- All accounts for the user should be fetched from the backend and loaded to the store.
- URL should change to /accounts/1111 where 1111 is the first element in the account list, and therefore fetch the details of account 1111 from backend and load them into the store.

I have tried different approaches, including calling router.navigate from the accounts resolver but it gets me in an infinite loop on that resolver. Besides, in the accounts resolver itself I dont even know how to differentiate between /accounts and /accounts/2222 so that I would only call navigate in case that accountNumber is not given.

accounts resolver:

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<Array<Account>> | Promise<Array<Account>> | Array<Account> | any {

    const webUserId = '150104';

    return this.store.pipe(
      select(selectEnrolledAccounts),
      tap(() =>
        this.store.dispatch(new EnrolledAccountsRequested({webUserId}))),
      filter(accounts => accounts.length > 0),
      first()
    );
  }
```

:accountNumber resolver

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<Account> | Promise<Account> | Account | any {

    const accountNumber = route.paramMap.get('accountNumber');

    return this.store.pipe(
      select(selectAccountNumberSelected),
      tap(() =>
        this.store.dispatch(new AccountSelected({accountNumber}))),
      filter(an => !!an),
      first()
    );
  }
```

So when the user tried to load just /accounts I tried to do some navigation within the accounts resolver

```
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
    Observable<Array<Account>> | Promise<Array<Account>> | Array<Account> | any {

    const webUserId = '150104';
    const accountNumber = route.paramMap.get('accountNumber');

    return this.store.pipe(
      select(selectEnrolledAccounts),
      tap(() =>
        this.store.dispatch(new EnrolledAccountsRequested({webUserId}))),
      filter(accounts => accounts.length > 0),
      mergeMap(accounts => {
        if (!accountNumber) {
          this.router.navigate(['accounts', accounts[0].accountNumber, 'home']);
          return of(accounts); //EMPTY;
        } else {
          return of(accounts);
        }

      }),
      first()
    );
  }
```

But this solution does not work, including that the accountNumber will not be available as a param in this resolver, so I can't distinguish if the full url has already specified an account number.

Answer (score 0):

This would be best served by using a CanActivateGuard on your /accounts route. Since you are using NGRX, you can fire the action to get all the accounts from the guard if you don't have them already, and then return an observable that waits for the full list to come back. Once it comes back, you can map that to the URL tree for the /accounts/1111 route.

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: I don't think for the purpose described in this case, the CanActivate is any different than the Resolve which I posted. You will run into the same issues. When the router is in the /accounts resolver (or canActivate) does not get passed the :accountNumber as a param because it is a child. So that resolver can not make a decision whether to proceed with a given accountNumber or to default into the first element.

Comment: Because the guard is passed the route snapshot, and the route is a hierarchy, you can search down the firstChild of the snapshot to see if there is an :accountNumber in the child route.